# Using a second signing card with the same sponsor cert

Tags: verifone

I have 2 file signing cards with the same "sponsor" (obviously, the actual "signer" is different between the 2).  Until quite recently, I've only been using the one but today I tried using the other.  I built my application and signed it using the same process I always use and I downloaded both the `.out` and the `.p7s` files the same way I always do, but when the download finishes, I get an error message about the signature not matching.

I was pretty sure that you could use 2 different signing cards as long as the sponsor was the same between them.  Am I wrong?  What am I missing?

For the record:

- This is for a Vx520
- My terminal is on the latest OS
- I have verified that the sponsor certificate name on the terminal's boot up screen matches the sponsor cert name in the signing tool's diagnostics menu
- My terminal also has VMAC and CommServer, but no other programs on it (besides the one I built and am trying to download and run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the file signing tool runs, it generates the `.p7s` file, which is always required, but it also generates a file `Certif.crt`.  This file is not necessary to download to the terminal if you are only using a single signing card, but if you use a second card, you MUST download it along with the `.p7s`.  From what I can tell, this `.crt` file is what the terminal uses to determine that the sponsors are the same.  Once I downloaded the `.crt` file along with everything else, it worked.

Side note: The tool also generates a `SponsorCertif.crt` file.  I'm not using that nor do I know what scenarios would require it... If you know, please comment below.